# Prolog - How to count elements of a list?

Tags: list, prolog

Based that we have 1 list and we want to count how many times we found each element on that list, and make a new list that contains an element of the format `N*X`, for each element `X` that shows up `N` times in the given list.

I have to write a program in Prolog that utilizes that construction. More specifically a predicate `freq(L,S)`, which is true if `S` is a list with elements with `N*X` format, in which the element `N*X` is included exactly one time if and only if the element `X` is included exactly `N` times inside the list `L`.

Here are some examples, the order of list S doesn't matter

```
| ?- freq([],S).
S = []

| ?- freq([a,b,c],S).
S = [1*a,1*b,1*c]

| ?- freq([0,0,0,0,0,a,a,a],S).
S = [5*0,3*a]

| ?- freq([5,5,5],S).
S = [3*5]

| ?- freq([a,a,0,a,0,0,0,b,a,0],S).
S = [5*0,4*a,1*b]
```

We use GNU-Prolog and we can't import any libraries other than the defaults.

Comment: I hope that one day homework will be given in unit test code. The cleartext specs are so _passé_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution using only `mebmer/2`, `findall/3` and `nth/3`. Moreover, if you do not want to use `findall/3` and `nth/3` you can write your own predicate to count the occurrences of elements in the list (and it will be faster):

```
freq([],[]).
freq(L,LO):-
    msort(L,LS),
    freq_(LS,LS,[],LO).
freq_([],_,L,L).
freq_([H|T],LI,LT,L):-
    member(_*H,LT), !,
    freq_(T,LI,LT,L).
freq_([H|T],LI,LT,L):-
    findall(I,nth0(I,LI,H),LO),
    length(LO,N),
    append(LT,[N*H],L1),
    freq_(T,LI,L1,L).

?- freq([a,a,0,a,0,0,0,b,a,0],S).
S = [5*0, 4*a, 1*b]
```

Answer (score 1):

library([aggregate](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) is on purpose:

```erlang
freq(L,F) :- findall(N*E,aggregate(count,member(E,L),N),F).
```

Comment: I always forget about that.

Answer (score 0):

How about this. With Unit Tests.

```
:- discontiguous rt/1.     % unit test invocation predicate

rtall :- bagof(X,rt(X),_). % run all unit tests by calling all rt/1

% ===
% Something to replace (badly named & ugly) "var(X)" and "nonvar(X)"
% ===

% is X referencing a fresh/unbound/uninstantiated term?
% ("is X a freshvar"?)

ff(X) :- var(X).    

% is X referencing an nonfresh/bound/instantiated term?
% ("is X a boundvar"?)

bb(X) :- nonvar(X). 

% ===
% increment(+Key,+ListIn,-ListOut)
% Increments-by-1 or adds Key-with-1 to ListIn, giving ListOut
% ===

increment(Key,[],[*(1,Key)]) :- !.
increment(Key,[*(N,Key)|Rest],[*(NP,Key)|Rest]) :-
   succ(N,NP),!.
increment(Key,[*(N,SomeKey)|Rest],[*(N,SomeKey)|ListOut]) :-
   SomeKey \== Key,!, increment(Key,Rest,ListOut).

% ---
% Testing the above
% ---

:- begin_tests(inc).

test(one,true(ListOut == [(1*foo)])) :-
   increment(foo,[],ListOut).

test(two,true(ListOut == [(2*foo)])) :-
   increment(foo,[],ListA),
   increment(foo,ListA,ListOut).

test(two,true(ListOut == [(2*foo),(1*bar)])) :-
   increment(bar,[(2*foo)],ListOut).

:- end_tests(inc).

rt(inc) :- run_tests(inc).

% ===
% freq(+Expanded,?Collapsed)
% Either accepts the "Expanded" list and builds the "Collapsed" list
% or, id "Collapsed" is a boundvar, builds a new "Collapsed" list
% and compares with the passed "Collapsed" list so that key positions
% are irrelevant
% ===

freq(Expanded,Collapsed) :-
   bb(Expanded),ff(Collapsed),!,
   freq_with_hot_potatoe(Expanded,[],Collapsed). 

freq(Expanded,Collapsed) :-
   bb(Expanded),bb(Collapsed),!,
   freq_with_hot_potatoe(Expanded,[],CollapsedNew), 
   compare_position_independently(Collapsed,CollapsedNew).

compare_position_independently(CollapsedA,CollapsedB) :-
   % sort to the "standard order of terms", keep duplicates
   msort(CollapsedA,CASorted),
   msort(CollapsedB,CBSorted),
   CASorted == CBSorted.

freq_with_hot_potatoe([X|Xs],CollapsedSoFar,CollapsedOut) :- 
   !,
   increment(X,CollapsedSoFar,CollapsedPass),
   freq_with_hot_potatoe(Xs,CollapsedPass,CollapsedOut).

freq_with_hot_potatoe([],Collapsed,Collapsed).

% ---
% Testing the above
% ---

:- begin_tests(freq).

test(f0)      :- freq([],[]).
test(f1,fail) :- freq([],[1*a]).
test(f2)      :- freq([a,b,c],[1*a,1*b,1*c]).
test(f3,fail) :- freq([a,b,c],[1*a,1*b,2*c]).
test(f4,fail) :- freq([a,b,c],[1*a,1*b,1*c,0*d]). % BORDERLINE, should succeed...
test(f5)      :- freq([a,b,c],[1*a,1*c,1*b]).     % Order unimportant
test(f6)      :- freq([0,0,0,0,0,a,a,a],[5*0,3*a]).
test(f7)      :- freq([5,5,5],[3*5]).
test(f8)      :- freq([a,a,0,a,0,0,0,b,a,0],[5*0,4*a,1*b]).

:- end_tests(freq).

rt(freq) :- run_tests(freq).
```

Running all tests:

```
?- rtall.
% PL-Unit: inc ... done
% All 3 tests passed
% PL-Unit: freq ......... done
% All 9 tests passed
true.
```